# How to calculate the checksum of the apk programmatically on the runtime

Tags: android, runtime, apk, checksum

How to calculate the checksum of the apk programmatically on the runtime,
so I can prevent a repackaged or recompiled apk from being able to do any harm (tamper prevention)
even if the resource files are changed in apk, the checksum needs to get changed.

gradle and api version which i am using currently

minsdkversion: 28
target sdk version: 33

gradle version :6.6.1

What I have come up with so far, is to calculate the checksum of the applicationInfo.publicSourceDir ,
still we dint get exact result.

so is there any way to calculate the checksum of the apk programmatically on the runtime.

Comment: You're wasting your time.  Even if you could do that, it would be trivially reverse engineered and removed.

Comment: Calculating a hash of a file is not that much of a problem. Simply get the APK file names and generate the hashes. But I would better check the signature instead of manually comparing the hashes. In the end may be an existing solution like [Play Integrity API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity) would be better.